# Migrate asp.net web site and error WAT070 on window azure sdk

Tags: asp.net, azure

I try to follow [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zkap/archive/2012/07/29/how-to-migrate-an-existing-asp-net-website-to-windows-azure.aspx)  for migrate asp.net site to windows azure.After `Convert to Web Application` when I try to debug I got a following error.

`Error  106 WAT070 : The referenced assembly path\Something.dll was not found. Please make sure to build the role project that produces this assembly before building this Windows Azure Cloud Service Project. C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Windows Azure Tools\1.8\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets    1253    5   TestCloud`

I try to add references from `C:\Program......` but it is not work.What is mistake and how to resolve this error.Thanks.